# Background Task Not Waiting For Bot To Be Ready

Tags: python, selenium, discord

So the goal of this background task is to wait until the bot is ready and then perform the function `monitorGame()`  unfortunately this is not the case when I run the bot.

Code With Problem:

```
import json
import requests
import discord
from gamestop import monitorGame
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
from discord.ext.commands import errors
from discord.utils import get
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Prefix
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/')
bot.remove_command("help")

# Bot Event
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("[+] Bot Is Alive [+]")
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=f"Game"))

# Start Monitor
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def monitor():

  # Wait Until Bot Is Ready
  await bot.wait_until_ready()

  # Run Function
  monitorGame()

# Start Task
monitor.start()

# Run bot
bot.run(token)
```

Since the function `monitorGame()` uses selenium, what tells me that the function is running before the bot is ready is that a browser opens before the bot prints `Bot Is Alive`.

What ends up happening is the function runs before the bot is ready and just screws everything up.

Some side notes:

- The function includes selenium and opens a browser.
- I am using repl to run this bot.
- The function `monitorGame()` essentially opens a browser and parses the html that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply check how long it takes to start up the selenium part, then mesure the time and insert a `time.sleep('seconds')` until it is started up, probably the easiest fix in this case